# bootstrap validator adds has-error class on valid input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I've created a form that is divided in 4 tabs, and i've added the bootstrap validator to the form to test the validity on the input.

On this jsfiddle.net i've recreated part of the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/2sgmkdnf/1/

When you press submit without entering any data into the form, it will display the X symbol and color the input red. As it should.

However, other input that are valid also show red. It does show the ok symbol. but the box is colored red.

Im i doing something wrong?

html

```
<form method="post" id="mainForm">
    <div id="content">
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#regi" data-toggle="tab" class="tab" id="regi_tab">Registrant</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#admin" data-toggle="tab" class="tab" id="admin_tab">Administrative</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tech" data-toggle="tab" class="tab" id="tech_tab">Technical</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#billing" data-toggle="tab" class="tab" id="billing_tab">Billing</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active form-group" id="regi">
                    <h3>Registrant</h3>

                <div style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="regi_form_fname" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="regi_form_lname" type="text" value="Doe DOE">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="admin">
                    <h3>Administrative</h3>

                <div style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="admin_form_fname" type="text" value="John harry">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="admin_form_lname" type="text" value="Doe DOE">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tech">
                    <h3>Technical</h3>

                <div style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="tech_form_fname" type="text" value="John harry">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="tech_form_lname" type="text" value="Doe DOE">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="billing">
                    <h3>Billing</h3>

                <div style="width:300px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="billing_form_fname" type="text" value="John harry">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Names</label>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" name="billing_form_lname" type="text" value="Doe DOE">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-success" name="dosubmit" type="submit" value="Update Domain Contacts">
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mainForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            'regi_form_fname': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'regi_form_lname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'admin_form_fname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'admin_form_lname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'tech_form_fname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'tech_form_lname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'billing_form_fname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
                'billing_form_lname': {
                validators: {

                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'This field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Cannot be longer then 30 characters'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a little tricky. The catch was you added the `.form-group` class to the `#regi` container over both fields and when the first one had an error, the `#regi` container was added the `.has-error` class so the whole thing was invalid (adding by mistake the `.has-error` to the valid field).

Remove `form-group` on this line :

```
<div class="tab-pane active form-group" id="regi">
```

to make it :

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="regi">
```

This should fix it :)